# "Unable to retrieve Drone Instance within 60 seconds"

Tags: jakarta-ee, selenium-webdriver, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone, graphene2

I am learning Java EE 7 using a German book called [Workshop Java EE 7](https://www.dpunkt.de/buecher/4861/workshop-java-ee-7.html), which basically takes one by the hand to build a running sample application. In the second "iteration" of the book, integration tests are being defined ([GitHub branch](https://github.com/marcusschiesser/my-aktion-2nd/tree/tests/)). However, I cannot get them to run. When I start up WildFly and then do `mvn verify`, Firefox opens up with "no available windows", and after 60 seconds, it crashes and I get a long list of errors (see below). I have been googling all the error messages, and even though there are many similar problems discussed on various platforms (including StackOverflow), none of the answers I found did fix my issue. Since the authors made the entire project available online, I can point you to the relevant parts of the code:

- [pom.xml](https://github.com/marcusschiesser/my-aktion-2nd/blob/tests/my-aktion/pom.xml)
- [arquillian.xml](https://github.com/marcusschiesser/my-aktion-2nd/blob/tests/my-aktion/src/test/resources/arquillian.xml)
- [AbstractITCase.java](https://github.com/marcusschiesser/my-aktion-2nd/blob/tests/my-aktion/src/test/java/de/dpunkt/myaktion/test/AbstractITCase.java)
- [DonateMoneyITCase.java](https://github.com/marcusschiesser/my-aktion-2nd/blob/tests/my-aktion/src/test/java/de/dpunkt/myaktion/test/DonateMoneyITCase.java)

I hope you can help me resolve this issue, especially since I am sure it is also relevant to many other readers of the book, which is among the top Java EE books on amazon.de. Thank you so much in advance!

I am using macOS 10.12, Java 8, WildFly 8.1.0 and Firefox 57.

Find below the shortened console output of the error messages:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.exception.PageObjectInitializationException: Can not instantiate Page Object
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to retrieve Drone Instance within 60 seconds
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
de.dpunkt.myaktion.test.DonateMoneyITCase  Time elapsed: 60.247 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected callable present in Drone Context, should be already instantiated at this moment.
```

Find below the full console output of the error messages:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running de.dpunkt.myaktion.test.DonateMoneyITCase
Jan 01, 2018 10:29:47 PM org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.factory.remote.reusable.ReusedSessionPermanentFileStorage readStore
Jan 01, 2018 10:29:47 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.0.Beta4
Jan 01, 2018 10:29:47 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.0.Beta4
Jan 01, 2018 10:29:47 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version (unknown)
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 76.412 sec <<< FAILURE! - in de.dpunkt.myaktion.test.DonateMoneyITCase
testDonateMoney(de.dpunkt.myaktion.test.DonateMoneyITCase)  Time elapsed: 60.225 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.exception.PageObjectInitializationException: Can not instantiate Page Object 
class de.dpunkt.myaktion.test.pages.DonateMoneyPage
 declared in: 
de.dpunkt.myaktion.test.DonateMoneyITCase

        at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.PageObjectEnricher.enrich(PageObjectEnricher.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.GrapheneEnricher.enrich(GrapheneEnricher.java:51)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestInstanceEnricher.enrich(TestInstanceEnricher.java:52)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.ClientTestInstanceEnricher.enrich(ClientTestInstanceEnricher.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:102)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.before(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:222)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:240)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:185)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to retrieve Drone Instance within 60 seconds
        at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneInstanceCreator.createDroneInstance(DroneInstanceCreator.java:98)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneTestEnricher.getDroneInstance(DroneTestEnricher.java:114)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneTestEnricher.enrich(DroneTestEnricher.java:75)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.AbstractSearchContextEnricher.enrichRecursively(AbstractSearchContextEnricher.java:70)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.PageObjectEnricher.setupPage(PageObjectEnricher.java:97)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.PageObjectEnricher.enrich(PageObjectEnricher.java:75)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.GrapheneEnricher.enrich(GrapheneEnricher.java:51)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestInstanceEnricher.enrich(TestInstanceEnricher.java:52)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.ClientTestInstanceEnricher.enrich(ClientTestInstanceEnricher.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:102)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.before(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:222)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:240)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:185)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneInstanceCreator.createDroneInstance(DroneInstanceCreator.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneTestEnricher.getDroneInstance(DroneTestEnricher.java:114)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneTestEnricher.enrich(DroneTestEnricher.java:75)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.AbstractSearchContextEnricher.enrichRecursively(AbstractSearchContextEnricher.java:70)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.PageObjectEnricher.setupPage(PageObjectEnricher.java:97)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.PageObjectEnricher.enrich(PageObjectEnricher.java:75)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.graphene.enricher.GrapheneEnricher.enrich(GrapheneEnricher.java:51)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestInstanceEnricher.enrich(TestInstanceEnricher.java:52)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.ClientTestInstanceEnricher.enrich(ClientTestInstanceEnricher.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:102)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.before(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:222)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:240)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:185)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

de.dpunkt.myaktion.test.DonateMoneyITCase  Time elapsed: 60.247 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected callable present in Drone Context, should be already instantiated at this moment.
        at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.InstanceOrCallableInstanceImpl.asInstance(InstanceOrCallableInstanceImpl.java:57)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneEnhancer.deenhanceDrone(DroneEnhancer.java:119)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneDestructor.destroyClassScopedDrone(DroneDestructor.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.afterClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:87)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3$1.evaluate(Arquillian.java:204)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

<some other test cases left out for brevity>
```

Comment: Problem suggests that browser didn't respond. I see in `arquillian.xml` that webdriver is set to `firefox`. Try `htmlunit` or `phantomjs` instead, both are integrated headless browsers. If that works, then problem is not in Arquillian side.

Comment: Thank you, @BakusC. I did try with `phantomjs` earlier, also with `safari`. These attempts failed with similar error messages. When I am home tonight, I'll post them as well. Have you tried to run the project? Does it work on your machine?

Comment: I haven't tried your project yet. I'm just a long time user of Arquillian+Graphene (using in a.o. https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces and https://github.com/omnifaces/optimusfaces)

Comment: Can you try following configuration in pom.xml  <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.failsafe.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a current (or unsupported?) version of Firefox might just take too long. This is at least what was happening when trying the project out as-is under Linux (I don't have a Mac at hand). Increasing the timeout by adding

```
<extension qualifier="drone">
    <property name="instantiationTimeoutInSeconds">120</property>
</extension>
```

to `arquillian.xml` makes the `TimeoutException` go away *on my device* using Firefox 57.

Unfortunately the tests now fail with `org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7057 after 45000 ms.`. No web page was loaded in Firefox. The [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG) reveals that the latest supported Firefox version for Selenium 2.39 seems to be 26.0.

Explicitly using this version (via `<property name="firefox_binary">/path/to/firefox-26.0/firefox</property>` in the webdriver configuration in `arquillian.xml`) then leads to `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button/span[text()='Aktion hinzufügen']"}`, but this time an application is shown (in *English* as this is my OS's setting). Changing `AbstractPage#getString` to use the *English* resource bundle finally makes the tests green. So maybe do not base your selectors on localized button labels ...

Interestingly enough using `phantomjs` just works here (but this time only with the *German* `ResourceBundle`).

Environment:

- Ubuntu 17.10 on x86_64
- Firefox 57 (initially) and 26
- Maven 3.5.0
- OpenJDK 1.8.0_151 (Ubuntu repo)
- WildFly 8.1.0

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run `mvn verify` and it failed on my machine, most probably because the firefox version on my machine was too new for the Selenium driver there.

@Rene in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48101700/808237) fixes that by substituting the proper Firefox version, I decided to upgrade Arquillian components. So here is the fixed code:

1. [Changes](https://github.com/tsabirgaliev/my-aktion-2nd/commit/8826e736381fd47f2f8d6554988a8e173df026c2) to make things run with Firefox 57.
2. The `test` [branch in my fork](https://github.com/tsabirgaliev/my-aktion-2nd/tree/tests) that incorporates the changes.